# Как отправить сообщение всем пользователям в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Почитал остальные темы ,они все старенькие и телебот обновлялся 50 раз уже, хотел бы обновить этой темой востребованность к этому вопросу. (сам пишу через telebot). Поэтому созрел такой вопрос, реально ли в современных реалиях сделать рассылку всем пользователям(или хотя бы выборочно)

Answer (score 0):

Ниже оставлю ссылку на источник, а здесь просто перепишу.
По идеи неплохой способ после каждого вызова бота от нового пользователя, записывать `id` юзера в базу данных или в отдельный файл.
Хочешь отправить сообщение всем пользователям? Обращайся к БД или файлу и пройтись по всем `id` юзеров и отправить всем сообщение.

https://qna.habr.com/q/490455

Comment: Я думаю, он хотел как-то разослать массово сообщение в обход лимита на число отправляемых сообщений, а не просто узнать, откуда id брать.

Comment: Если Вы пишете ответ,  то пишите его развёрнуто,  а не в виде ссылки. Внешняя ссылка может стать недоступна с течением времени.

Comment: @ReinRaus, так вроде он нормально написал?

Comment: а есть ли способ проще?

Comment: просто у моего бота уже более 400 юзеров(смотрю с внешнего конструкта) айди узнать не могу,а в бд(я ее создал недавно) всего лишь 10 человек)

Comment: @ReinRaus
А что я написал непонятного? Я ведь в начале сказал, что просто перепишу содержимое, а внизу на всякий оставил источник...